# Lync 2013 Android with OCS 2007 Backend

Tags: android, lync-2013

Just wondering whether anyone has any knowledge on how to potentially get the Lync client for Android working when there is an OCS 2007 server running in the backend. I was able to get the PC Lync client working via changing some of the registry settings but have not been able to find anything regarding getting the mobile client working. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Cheers
Ambrose